# Sending form like object through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a web page which allows users to update their recipes. On this page I have a simple form for users who don't have javascript, and I have AJAX functionality for users who do have javascript. When I submit my form, it binds to my MVC model perfectly and everything goes well. Here is an example of the form request:

[image]

As you can see, my `Ingredients` array contains an object, with the properties `Ingredient` and `Optional`. This all works out fine.

The problem comes when I try to submit an AJAX request with supposedly the exact same structure as my form. Here is a screenshot of an AJAX request.

[image]

As you can see, instead of being laid out as `Ingredients[index].Ingredient` it is `Ingredients[index][Ingredient]`. This ruins MVC's model binding and I can't access any of the properties. The `Steps` array still binds fine even though it is missing it's index number.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/update_rec',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: ajaxrecipe,
        error: function () {
            alert("There was an error updating your recipe, please try again");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

Here is the structure of `ajaxrecipe`

```
var ajaxrecipe =
        {
            RecipeId: $('input#RecipeId').val(),
            RecipeTitle: $('.recipe-information-area > h3.title').val(),
            Ingredients: [],
            Steps: []
        };

ajaxrecipe.Ingredients.push({ Ingredient: ingrediento, Optional: optionalo});
ajaxrecipe.Steps.push(step);
```

I have been scouring the web for solutions to this but they've all come up useless. I have tried `JSON.stringify`, `datatype: "json"`, `contenttype: "application/json charset utf-8"` and `traditional: true`.

If I could just get the AJAX request to submit the same way the form does, everything should work fine.

Comment: You are posting an object named `ajaxrecipe` but you have not shown how you construct it.  Are you inspecting us to guess?

Comment: I thought it would be obvious from the network requests, I'll add it the the question anyway.

Comment: Updated with the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to post your form controls, then you simply need

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("update_rec", "ajax")', // don't hard code your url's!
  data: $('form').serialize(), // serialize the form
  ....
```

If for some reason you need to manually construct the object using arrays, then you need to add the `traditional: true,` and stringify the object

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("update_rec", "ajax")',
  traditional: true,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify({ model: ajaxrecipe }), // assumes the method parameter is named 'model'
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

How familiar are you with model-binding?
I think the problem lies in your model itself, which you forgot to post.

It is entirely possible to make a model in C# and then bind it via the object you post (as `JSON`).

Let me give you an example:

The model:

```
public class Recipe 
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string RecipeTitle { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public List<string> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class Ingridient
{
    public string Ingridient { get; set; }
    public bool Optional { get; set; }
}
```

You can then make your controller accept the model as first argument.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("update_rec")]
public ActionResult UpdateRecipe(Recipe recipe)
{
    // do your logic.
}
```

Then you just have to make sure that your jQuery-code posts it correctly.

```
var ajaxrecipe = {
    RecipeId: $('input#RecipeId').val(),
    RecipeTitle: $('.recipe-information-area > h3.title').val(),
    Ingredients: [],
    Steps: []
};

ajaxrecipe.Ingredients.push({ Ingredient: ingrediento, Optional: optionalo});
ajaxrecipe.Steps.push(step);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax/update_rec',
    data: { recipe: JSON.stringify(ajaxrecipe) },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was an error updating your recipe, please try again");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

I have not tested this, but done similar things before.
Please tell me of your results!